# error in using case with like sql anywhere query

Tags: sql, sqlanywhere

I want to use like in case statement and search string from a particular colmun
if any part of that string contains 'Moderate to severe aortic stenosis' THEN  instead of full string I want to display 'Moderate to Severe'
if any part of that string contains 'Severe aortic stenosis with' THEN  instead of full string I want to display 'Severe'
if that string contains 'moderate aortic stenosis present' THEN  instead of full string I want to display 'Moderate'

Below is my query not working some systax error

```
SELECT (CASE  a.Column when  LIKE '%Moderate to severe aortic stenosis%' THEN 'Moderate to Severe'
            when  LIKE '%Severe aortic stenosis with%' THEN 'Severe'
            when  LIKE '%moderate aortic stenosis present%' THEN 'Moderate' else ' ' end)
       from MyTable a
```

Please help

Comment: My daughter was born with moderate to severe aortic stenosis. Keep up the good work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are syntax errors in your query:

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
     WHEN a.Column LIKE '%Moderate to severe aortic stenosis%' THEN 'Moderate to Severe'
     WHEN a.Column LIKE '%Severe aortic stenosis with%' THEN 'Severe'
     WHEN a.Column LIKE '%moderate aortic stenosis present%' THEN 'Moderate' else ' ' 
  END
FROM 
 MyTable a
```

Field `a.Column` should ***appear after every*** `WHEN` in comparison with `LIKE`.

Comment: @Jim "*Column should appear after every WHEN*" is not entirely true. For equality conditions (`=`) it is allowed to have it only once: `case some_col when 1 the 'foo' when 2 then 'bar' else 'foobar' end` is valid SQL. But this **only** works for a comparison with `=` not for anything else and that's why for `LIKE` the column must be repeated

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing the error message it's hard to tell what the problem is.

But I suspect you want to write this like this:

```
SELECT CASE when a.Column LIKE '%Moderate to severe aortic stenosis%' THEN 'Moderate to Severe'
            when a.Column LIKE '%Severe aortic stenosis with%' THEN 'Severe'
            when a.Column LIKE '%moderate aortic stenosis present%' THEN 'Moderate' 
            else ' ' 
       end
       from MyTable a
```

I've moved the a.Column into the when portion of the case statement. I think you can only move it outside when doing an equality comparison rather than a fuzzy match.